# Is the inverse image of an irreducible variety under the natural projection irreducible (in the setting of homogeneous spaces)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $p\colon Z\to X$ be a morphism between irreducible varieties (= reduced schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$). Assume that every fiber of $p$ over a closed point of $X$ is also irreducible. Let $X'$ be an irreducible subvariety of $X$. My question is: under which circumstances can we say that the inverse image $p^{-1}(X')$ is also irreducible? Can someone give an example of a situation where it is not irreducible?

I was thinking about a solution like this which is likely to be flawed because I am lacking experience: let $\eta$ be the generic point of $X'$. Since all fibers of $p$ over closed points are irreducibel we can conclude that $p^{-1}(\eta)$ is also irreducible. By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289979/there-is-a-bijection-between-irreducible-components-of-the-generic-fiber-and-irr) the irreducible components of $p^{-1}(\eta)$ and $p^{-1}(X')$ are in one to one correspondence. Since $p^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreducible it follows that $p^{-1}(X')$ is also irreducible.

I think that this solution is flawed because I am using arguments which I cannot justify rigorously, for example I do not know if the fiber over $\eta$ is irreducible. (Note that this point will usually not be closed.)

The precise situation I have in mind is the following. It might be superfluous to say this but I want to be sure... Let $G$ be a simple, simply connected and connected linear algebraic group. Let $P$ be a (maximal) parabolic subgroup. Let $Z=G$ and $X=G/P$ and $p$ the natural projection. Let $X'$ be a Schubert variety in $X$. The fibers of $p$ over a closed (or any?) point is isomorphic to $P$, hence irreducible. In this specific situation it might be even possible to argue using that $p$ is open or closed? (I think $p$ is open but not closed but I am quite unsure. If it is closed we can conclude directly as far as I see.)

If someone can say a few words which yield to clarification I would be very happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious place this fails is when $p$ is the blowing up of say, a smooth point in $X$ ($\dim X\geq 2$). Then all fibers of closed points are either a point or a projective space. But the inverse image of any irreducible curve through the blown up point is not irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mohan. You are totally right. But I am rather looking for an affirmative answer in the case I have in mind (concerning homogeneous spaces) and was trying to abstract from the situation. To put it more concretely, let $w$ be a Weyl group element, why is $\bigcup_{v\preceq w}BvP$ irreducible where $\preceq$ denotes the Bruhat order on $X$ (with the notation as in the question). Concerning your example, I was wondering if the generic fiber $p^{-1}(\eta)$ is irreducible in this case.